# How to set timezone when save and retrieve data on Magento

Tags: admin, php

I've changed the

```
System->Configuration->General->Locale Options->Timezone
```

to ID and saved.

the data is **2013-09-30 12:03** when saved.

but when i see on Admin Grid the data is : **Sep 30, 2013 7:03:00 PM**

and when i edit it. it shows **2013-09-30 12:03**

on the database the data is **2013-09-30 12:03:00**

The weird thing is on Admin Grid, the data isn't the same with the database.

Comment: The weird thing is not that the date is not the same on the grid as in the database. This is normal if the timezone is not GMT+0. The strange thing is that it's not the same in the edit form as it is in the grid. Is this a custom from and grid or from a core module? if this is a custom module post the code from the form and grid.

Comment: @Marius $model->setCreatedAt(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()))); this is how to save.

Comment: @Marius How the correct way to save datetime in Magento?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but by looking at the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created` that is the backend model of the `created_at` attribute on the product I see that this is used `Varien_Date::now()`.

Comment: Hey @Marius you are correct! Thank you! But now i save data 2013-09-30 14:18, and now on database it show: 2013-09-30 14:18:00. and it will be converted when the data show on grid: 30 Sep 2013 21:18:00. how to fix that?

Comment: The point is, How to convert the data to Varien_Date then save it?

Comment: Humm, a little curious, how about Zend_Date::now() ? this is correct too

Comment: After doing some digging I'm not sure anymore that this is the way to go. I will dig even deeper and post an answer if I find one.

Comment: I'll be waiting for the answer. . .

Comment: OK this is the answer for the confusing timezone! Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s', null)

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano please add your solution and mark it as solved. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, however the way i fixed it is like this in Grid.php:

`$this->addColumn ('module_date', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Start Date'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()
                ->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM),
    'type' => 'date',
    'width' => '200px',
    'index' => 'module_date'
));`

add the `format` index with its value as given above and set the `type` to `'date'`. Do NOT use `datetime` as type.

Hope it helps.